# AngularJS: How do I return the original element, with a new sibling element, in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this markup:

```
<a href="/" myDirective="Text 1 2 3 Foo">Link</a>
```

How can I end up with this output using a directive?

```
<a class="tooltip" style="left:<the left pos of the original element>; top:<the top pos of the original element>;">Text 1 2 3 Foo</a>
<a href="/">Link</a>
```

Thanks.

EDIT (another example):

```
<div myDirective="Text 1 2 3 Foo">
  <ul>
    <li>Bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Gives:

```
<a class="tooltip" style="left:<the left pos of the original element>; top:<the top pos of the original element>;">Text 1 2 3 Foo</a>
<div myDirective="Text 1 2 3 Foo">
  <ul>
    <li>Bar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So I essentially want to insert the tooltip element before the given element, but preserve the given element upon output and not replace it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
                template: "<a class="tooltip" >{{txt}}</a><a href="/">Link</a>",
                restrict : 'A',
                scope: { txt : "@myDirective" },
                replace: true,
            link: function(scope,elm,attrs) {

            }
    }
})
```

Although I'm pretty sure that Angular requires to have one element replacing another. So if the code above shouldn't work use this (wrap it with a span):

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
        return {
                    template: "<span><a class="tooltip" >{{txt}}</a><a href="/">Link</a></span>",
                    restrict : 'A',
                    scope: { txt : "@myDirective" },
                    replace: true,
                link: function(scope,elm,attrs) {

                }
        }
    })
```

Cheers, Heinrich

**UPDATE**:
Generic way as requested:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
                template: '<span bind-html-unsafe="{{tmp}}"></span>',
                restrict : 'A',
                scope: { txt : "@myDirective" },
                replace: true,
            link: function(scope,elm,attrs) {
                scope.tmp = '<'+attrs.tag+' class="tooltip" >{{txt}}</'+attrs.tag+'><a href="/">Link</a>'
            }
    }
})
```

your html:

```
<legend myDirective="A Text" tag="legend"></legend>
```

I see you are new to angular so pay attention to the new scope created here. You can access the parent vars with {{$parent.var}} if you need to. But you shouldn't. Better to pass em as attributes if there aren't too much of them.

**FINAL UPDATE**
tryout @ http://plnkr.co/edit/JSOH0cGcYiJIWsVkB8cP 
what you can do is to use $compile to do custom templating.

```
.directive('directive', function($compile) {
    return {
          restrict : 'A',
          scope: { txt : "@directive" },
          replace: true,
        compile: function compile(elm, attrs, transclude) {
        var e = elm;
        e.removeAttr("directive");

        elm.replaceWith('<span directive="'+attrs.directive+'"><a class="tooltip" href="">{{txt}}</a>'+e[0].outerHTML+'</span>');
            elm.append(e);
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 

                },
                post: function postLink(scope, elm, iAttrs, controller) { 
                    $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

your HTML template:

```
<div directive="{{text}}">
        <ul><li>list element</li></ul>
    </div>
```

good luck.
Cheers, Heinrich

Comment: Is there a more generic way, so that it would work with any element the directive is added to? I.e. can I pass-through the elm to the template? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I think I was explaining myself a bit badly though, I edited the question with another example input and output. Sorry for the bad wording at first, I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I'll post an update soon. there is a possibility using $compile to achieve what you want.